# Rearrange a Triple Summation with constraints

Tags: summation, summation-by-parts

I have the following triple summation: 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=0}^{m_0}\sum_{j=0}^m
    \sum_{k=0}^{2m_0-2j}
a_{kjm}
    x^{2(j+k)}
\end{equation}
I think I should be able to simplify it to something like:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{l=0}^{2m_0}
    b_l x^{2l}\,.
\end{equation}

My questions is how can I relate the $a_{kjm}$ coefficient with the $b_{l}$ coefficient.
Any clue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^{m_0}\sum_{j=0}^m
\sum_{k=0}^{2m_0-2j}a_{kjm}x^{2(j+k)}
& = \sum_{j=0}^{m_0}\sum_{m=j}^{m_0}
\sum_{k=0}^{2m_0-2j}a_{kjm}x^{2(j+k)} \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{m_0}\sum_{k=0}^{2m_0-2j}
\left(\sum_{m=j}^{m_0}a_{kjm}\right)x^{2(j+k)} \\
& = \sum_{l=0}^{2m_0}
\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{l,2m_0-l\}}
\sum_{m=j}^{m_0}a_{l-j,j,m}\right)x^{2l}.
\end{align*}
This uses the answer to [Double Summation indexes problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3609383). ("The", because the answers now agree!)

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I forgot to answer my own question. I had already solved it.